# Where can I find a breakdown of Google stock ownership?

Tags: online-tools, online-data-source, stock-analysis

I'm looking for a not too out of date source of information that lists who owns Google stock and how much they own. Is this available online somewhere?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Expected this to be a bit easier than it was, but dug around for a while and found what I hope is deep enough answer for your situation.

Here's the live report on NASDAQ's site:
http://www.nasdaq.com/asp/holdings.asp?symbol=GOOG&selected=GOOG

## Top 5 Holders

FMR LLC  15,335,005
CAPITAL RESEARC...   12,730,080
PRICE T ROWE AS...   10,054,346
VANGUARD GROUP ...   9,220,692
STATE STREET CO...   8,476,124

You can **page almost endlessly through the rest of the institutional owners** here:
http://holdings.nasdaq.com/asp/Institutional.asp?FormType=Institutional&SortBy=shares_held&Descending=D&strFilter=T&coname=Google+Inc.&logopath=http://content.nasdaq.com/logos/GOOG.gif&market=NASDAQ-GS&selected=GOOG&symbol=GOOG&PageNum=2

## Insider Control Note

Larry, Sergei & Eric Schmidt together own >90% of the Class B shares of the stock, which have 10 votes each (vs. 1 vote per Class A share), so they apparently control 68% of all voting rights in the company (think I read that in their latest 10Q)

## Freshness

Looks like that report is actually refreshed (via SEC Form 4 filings) on a daily basis, w/ the baselines taken from quarterly 13F filings - not sure, that's all new to me, took that from description offered on site, here:

"The data displayed in the Holdings Summary provides a snapshot of institutional holdings and activity for a particular stock.  The institutional holdings summary data encompasses the holdings and change from most recent 13F filings.  The insider filer data counts the number of monthly positions over 3 month and 12 month time spans.  Summary data is calculated daily, using the most up to date information available."

## Further Info

While the report's on NASDAQ.com, it's apparently sourced from EDGAR Online, so if the depth/formatting of the NASDAQ report isn't what you're looking for, you might try that too.

Comment: Is there somewhere for me to see the insider controlled shares?

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for.

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOG/holders?p=GOOG